# Does OEIS sequence A059046 contain any odd squares $u^2$, with $\omega(u) \geq 2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, oeis

Does [OEIS sequence A059046](http://oeis.org/A059046) contain any odd squares $u^2$, with $\omega(u) \geq 2$ (where $\omega(x)$ is the number of **distinct prime factors** of $x$)?

Here are the first sixty-two terms:

> A059046 - Numbers $n$ such that $\sigma(n)-n$ divides $n-1$.
>
> $2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 59, 61, 64, 67, 71, 73, 77, 79, 81, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 121, 125, 127, 128, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 169, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211$

So, for example:
$$\sigma({3^2}{5^2}) - 225 = {13}\cdot{31} - 225 = 403 - 225 = 178 \nmid 224,$$
so that $225$ is *not* in the sequence.

Without the constraint on the number of distinct prime factors $\omega(u')$, $u' = 9, 25, 49, 81, 121, 169, \ldots$.

[image: OEIS sequence A059046]

Comment: What is the motivation for this question ?

Comment: It's worth including the definition of the sequence - the image is hard for my poor eyes to read.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: *"Numbers n such that sigma(n)-n divides n-1"* for example *"For x=77, sigma(77)=96, 96-77=19, which divides 77-1."*

Comment: Put it in the question, @Henry. People should not have to read comments to know the question. And, except in rare occasions, people should not have to follow links.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I would not object if you did

Comment: The squares upto $33,000,001^2$ with the desired property are not in the sequence.

Comment: Thanks for checking, @Peter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked that there are no such squares with $u^2<10^{12}$ using this simple [GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) script:

```
is(n)=(n-1)%(sigma(n)-n)==0
forcomposite(n=6,1e6,if(is(n^2)&&!isprimepower(n), print(n)))
```

I then used [A059047](https://oeis.org/A059047) to check that there are no such squares with $u^2<10^{22}.$ Total computing time was about 12 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for checking and for your answer, @Charles.  I will wait for a couple more days and will accept your answer if there are no others.  =)

Comment: Such kind of casual proofs are disregarded FYI

Comment: @Idle I’m not sure what you mean, would you clarify?