# Search limit for almost perfect numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, divisor-sum

The function $$\sigma(n)$$ denotes the sum of the divisors of $n$. Perfect numbers are positive integers $n$ with $$\sigma(n)=2n$$ almost perfect numbers are  positive integers $n$ with $$\sigma(n)=2n-1$$ For the case $$\sigma(n)=2n+1$$ I found a search-limit on mathworld, but for "$2n-1$" I only found that it is conjectured that the only solutions are powers of $2$

> Does anyone know a reference for a search limit for the almost perfect numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is for the case of even almost perfect numbers (other than the powers of two).

(The following are taken from this [preprint by Antalan and Dris](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04248).)

Antalan and Tagle showed that an even almost perfect number $n \neq 2^t$ must necessarily have the form $2^r b^2$ where $r \geq 1$, $\gcd(2,b)=1$, and $b$ is an odd composite.

Since $2^r b^2$ is almost perfect and $\gcd(2,b)=1$, then we have
$$(2^{r+1} - 1)\sigma(b^2) = \sigma(2^r)\sigma(b^2) = \sigma(2^r b^2) = 2^{r+1} b^2 - 1$$
from which it follows that
$$1=(1-2^{r+1})\sigma(b^2) + 2^{r+1} b^2$$
$$2^{r+1} (\sigma(b^2) - b^2) = \sigma(b^2) - 1$$
$$2^{r+1} = \frac{\sigma(b^2) - 1}{\sigma(b^2) - b^2} = 1 + \frac{b^2 - 1}{\sigma(b^2) - b^2}$$

This last equation gives the divisibility constraint in the following result:

> If $2^r b^2$ is an almost perfect number with $\gcd(2,b)=1$ and $b>1$, then
>   $$(\sigma(b^2) - b^2) \mid (b^2 - 1).$$

Numbers $n$ such that $\sigma(n) − n$ divides $n − 1$ are listed in [OEIS sequence A059046](http://oeis.org/A059046), the first $62$ terms of which are given below:

$$2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 59, 61,$$
$$64, 67, 71, 73, 77, 79, 81, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 121, 125, 127, 128, 131, 137, 139,$$
$$149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 169, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211.$$

> **Remark:** Does OEIS sequence A059046 contain any odd squares $u^2$, with $\omega(u) \geq 2$?  [MSE user Charles](http://math.stackexchange.com/u/1778) checked and found
>   that "there are no such squares with $u^2 < {10}^{22}$." (See this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1466358) for Charles's answer.)

Comment: I think part of the difficulty is that, for the case of almost perfect numbers (other than the powers of two), we "do not have" a method similar to the factor chain approach that I think is only applicable for the case of odd perfect numbers.  This factor chain method has resulted in "better lower bounds" for the magnitude for an odd perfect number.

Comment: So, $10^{22}$ is a lower bound for a solution, right ?

Comment: @Peter, yes I think so.

Comment: Thank you, I anyway only wanted a search limit, whether a solution exists is apparently open.

Comment: @Peter:  For the case of odd almost perfect numbers I think you can use existing results on the minimum number of distinct prime factors that it can have.